# How to Use URL Parameters and Query Strings With React Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to get `foo` param value from `http://localhost:3000/params?foo=123`

But I'm getting this error:

**Error: Params(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.**

Why?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import React from "react";

export function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}
export function QueryScreen() {
  let query = useQuery();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{query.get("foo")}</h1>;
    </>
  );
}

export default function Params() {
  <Router>
    <QueryScreen />
  </Router>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done! This snippet solved my problem:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Items(props) {
  const { query } = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{query.foo}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```